# MySql Import freezed

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, import, console

I use a mysql import script like this.

```
sudo mysql -u root -p < /var/tmp/db.sql
```

I see that my data is beeing imported but the console is freezed.

```
root@****:/var/tmp# sudo mysql -u root -p < /var/tmp/db.sql
Enter password:
```

I have to type `STRG+C` to get the console back. Firstly i thought that the import just needs so much time, but i can wait hours, the console doesnt come back.

I am on ubuntu and the mysql file is round about 1GB.

Do you have any idea why the script freeze the console?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the answer on my own.

Setting this in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
init_connect='SET autocommit=0'
```

Now, the import takes about 2 Minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Importing 1GB took hours? That's not normal. You need to know what process is spending its time.

Try this:

```
$ ps -ef|grep [m]ysql
```

Identify the process id then,

```
$ strace -cp <pid>
```

Leave it 10 seconds or a minute then ^C. That will tell you where the process is spending its time, e.g. it could just be waiting for the disk if you seen read and write dominate.

Comment: Not the import took hours. Lets say after 5/10 Minutes is see all databases with data in it, but the console is freezed like i mentioned above. I must type `STRG+C` to use the console again.

Comment: I cant use your suggested method because in my db.sql are more than one database imports. If i try the strace i didnt get any output. In mysql log arent any information. Dont know why console freeze. ;(